# Awk find max and min per key

Tags: awk

I have a data look like this:
The highest and lowest midterm grade of each class in school A and school B (class not shown)

```
#school   highest  lowest
schoolA   99       53
schoolA   95       66
schoolA   88       48
schoolB   94       55
schoolB   91       36
```

I want to merge it like this:

```
schoolA   99       48
schoolB   94       36
```

the max and the min of each school are shown.
I have tried something like:

```
awk '
BEGIN{getline;min=$3;max=$2} 
{($3<min)?min=$3:"";($2>max)?max=$2:""} 
END{OFS="\t";print $1,max,min}
'
```

and it worked; however, it sometimes automatically plus one point at the min (the third column)

Could anyone teach me how to do this correctly and explain a little bit what does the code above mean? (especially the "getline") Can this code merge lines by column one (school)?

Answer (score 4):

If [datamash](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/) is okay:

```
$ datamash -W -g1 max 2 min 3 < ip.txt 
schoolA 99  48
schoolB 94  36
```

- `-W` to use whitespace as delimiter
- `-g1` group by 1st field
- `max 2 min 3` maximum of 2nd field and minimum of 3rd field
- if input file includes header line, use `--header-in` option to ignore it

Comment: with `sed 1d` perhaps easier to remove the header.

Comment: @karakfa yeah that's shorter :) also, I just checked man page and found there's built-in option in datamash itself...

Comment: I did not know [GNU datamash](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/). Now I do, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

first of all, I don't think your `(condition)?var=one:two` is correct. E.g:

```
awk 'BEGIN{(3>5)?a=1:2;print a}'
```

outputs nothing. It should be written in:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{a=(3>5)?1:2;print a}' 
2
```

- You don't need the `getline`.
- You didn't check the `school` therefor your codes will find min/max from all schools values.  It is not what you want.

For your problem, you can write like this:

```
awk -v OFS='\t' '$1 in min{min[$1]=$3<min[$1]?$3:min[$1]
               max[$1]=$2>max[$1]?$2:max[$1]
               next } {min[$1]=$3;max[$1]=$2}
            END{for(x in min)print x, max[x], min[x]}' file
```

Comment: Wow, thank you! I tried and it worked!! Could you tell me what does "$1 in min{..." means?

Comment: @Charlie - it's a condition. It evaluates as "true" if the first field from the current record exists as an index in the `min` array. So the block of code following the condition is evaluated if the `min` array has already been given initial variables, and this block of code ends with a `next`, meaning that the block of code right after it gets executed if the condition DOES NOT match.

Comment: The `(3>5?a=1:"")` evaluates to `""` which is a valid but obscure no-op. So it reads "if 3 is bigger than 5, assign a new value to `a`; else, do nothing."

Comment: ghoti and triplee Sorry for late reply...  thanks for your explanation!

Answer (score 0):

With POSIX awk, you can do:

```
awk ' BEGIN{fmt="%-15s%-10s%-10s\n"; printf fmt,"School","max","min"}
      !($1 in sch) {idx[++i]=$1; sch[$1]; arr[$1,"min"]=100}
      $2>arr[$1,"max"]{arr[$1,"max"]=$2}
      $3<arr[$1,"min"]{arr[$1,"min"]=$3}
      END{for (e=1;e<=length(idx);e++) printf fmt,idx[e],arr[idx[e],"max"],arr[idx[e],"min"]}' file
School         max       min       
schoolA        99        48        
schoolB        94        36
```

As written, this maintains file order for the schools printed. It is simpler to write if you do not care about the output order.

It is unclear if your file has a header or not.

If it DOES have a header, replace `printf fmt,"School","max","min"` with `FNR==1{printf fmt,$1,$2,$3}` to print the header. (or `FNR==1{next}` if you want to skip the header..)

Comment: Thanks for your detailed reply! But this is a little too complicate for me, I guess I will use the first solution by Kent or datamash.

Answer (score 0):

`getline` fetches the next input line. Doing this from the `BEGIN` block is kind of inelegant, though, as Awk will read every line anyway. I would do this instead:

```
NR==1{min=$3;max=$2;next}
```

to ensure that `max` and `min` are initialized to the values from the first line when the script starts.

The  `($3<min?min=$3:"")` and the corresponding statement for `$2` and `max` is pretty obscure. The construct `x ? y : z` is called the *ternary operator* and is a shorthand for `if (x) y; else z` so this evaluates to

```
if($3<min)
  min=$3
else
  ""
```

where `""` in this context is basically like a comment, i.e. a way to say explicitly "do nothing".

Your current script fetches the max and min overall. You apparently want to get the max and min separately for each key instead. Assuming all values for each school are adjacent,

```
NR>1 && $1!=prev { print prev, max, min }
NR==1 || $1!=prev { prev=$1; max=$2; min=$3 }
$2>max { max=$2 }
$3<min { min=$3 }
END { print prev, max, min }
```

If the input is sorted, at least enough that all mentions of one keyeare on adjacent lines, Awk can process a much larger input file, because it doesn't need to keep all keys in memory. Your sample file seems to have this property, so if it's representative, this should work. If not, maybe use `sort file | awk` (after discarding any header line, if present).

If the input file has a header, but it's already sorted, add `NR==1 { next }` at the top to skip it, and adjust the other `NR` mentions to compare to 2 instead of 1.

Comment: Thanks ! Seems a question can be solve by many different smart way!

Comment: @dawg Thanks for the feedback; updated slightly. Headers in CSV are a nuisance anyway.